# Javascript border change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website and I have 3 images with border-radius 50% (circled) and they have all a white border. But I need when I click at for example first one it takes a green border. and then if I click on the second image the first one deselects the green border and gets its default border and the second one now gets the green border...

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<img src=".">
<img src=".">
<img src=".">
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the images in a container element and attach a listener to it so you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch the click events from the images as they "bubble up" the DOM (rather than adding listeners to all the images), and use a class.

When an image is clicked remove the "green" class from all the images, and add it to the image that was clicked.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const images = container.querySelectorAll('img');

container.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
    images.forEach(image => image.classList.remove('green'));
    e.target.classList.add('green');
  }
}
```

```css
img { border: 5px solid white; }
.green { border: 5px solid green; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/555/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa/fff" />
</div>
```

Comment: this can also apply the class to the container itself and as such apply a border to it. To prevent that I would use `img.green` as the selector in the CSS. This should prevent the class from doing anything on the container.

Comment: Good spot. Thanks. @tacoshy.

Answer (score 1):

A CSS-only solution would be to use checkboxes. Then change the style for the selected checkbox with: `input:checked + label img { border: syntax green; }`

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label img {
  border: 5px solid green;
}



/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="image-1" name="image" value="huey"> 
<label for="image-1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">
</label>

<input type="radio" id="image-2" name="image" value="huey"> 
<label for="image-2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">
</label>

<input type="radio" id="image-3" name="image" value="huey"> 
<label for="image-3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">
</label>
```